# Present below current view and not above

Tags: swift, dismiss, presentviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a view controller below another presented view controller  (like WhatsApp when you open camera and press gallery).

I tried many things but none worked ..

Comment: What did you try? Have you got some code to share with us in order to help you?

Comment: Hello carmine I tried inserting the view below the presented one 
self.addChildViewController(newVC)
view.insertSubview(newVC.view, at: 0)
then self.dismiss 
but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use child view controller and set view of that added child view controller at the top of hierarchy. It will be top most element, so actual background of this view will be obscured, but that's the way to go.

```
//code inside UIViewController class
   func addViewControllerAtBottom() {
       let newVC = NewVCType() //just instantiate it
       addChildViewController(newVC)
       view.insertSubview(newVC.view, at: 0)  //at 0 means it's first rendered, all others will be on top of it
   }
```

Comment: Dear Adas 
I found something similar to your code but unfortunately both views get dismissed

Comment: What do you mean by "both views get dismissed", and what is second view of "both"? If self.view is not visible, then I can't help you without seeing code, how you load it.

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce this behavior by doing the following :

First, create a `NavigationController` with a root `ViewController` :

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstController)
```

Then, present this navigationController with `animated: false` and in the completion of the `present` method, push your second `ViewController`, still with `animated: false` (to avoid weird animations) :

```
    present(navController, animated: false) {
        navController.pushViewController(secondController, animated: false)
    }
```

Here you go, you got a new navigation with 2 `UIViewController`, like WhatsApp.

Full code, wrapped into a button's action :

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstController)

    present(navController, animated: false) {
        navController.pushViewController(secondController, animated: false)
    }
}
```